# Proving the convergence of $a_{n+2}=(a_{n+1}a_n)^{1/2} \qquad (a_1\ge0, a_2\ge0)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve exercise 8.10 from *Apostol-Mathematical Analysis*. I need to prove that the following sequence converges to $L=(a_1a_2^2)^{1/3}$.

$$a_{n+2}=(a_{n+1}a_n)^{1/2} \qquad (a_1\ge0, a_2\ge0)$$

I am studying $b_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}$ and $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

$$b_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}=b_1^{(-1/2)^n}$$
So I find that $\{b_n\}\to 1$. But now, I can't think of an intuitive way of continuing. Could you please give me a little hint?

Thank you.

Comment: Show that the map $[0,\infty)^2\to[0,\infty)^2$, $(x,y)\mapsto (y,\sqrt {xy})$ is a contraction

Comment: Your formula for $b_{n+1}$ was a little off, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sequence satisfies $(a_n a_{n+1}^2)^{1/3}= (a_1 a_2^2)^{1/3}=L$, i.e., this quantity is constant in $n$.
Now $${a_{n+2}\over L}={(a_n a_{n+1})^{1/2}\over L}
={(a_n a_{n+1})^{1/2}\over (a_n a_{n+1}^2)^{1/3}}=\left({a_n\over a_{n+1}}\right)^{1/6},$$
which converges to 1, as you have already shown. This gives  $a_{n+2}\to L$.

Comment: Very neat. Nice. (+1)

Comment: Byron, we showed that if the sequence converges, then it converges to $L$. But how can we be sure that it converges?

Comment: @Charlie You have already proved that $a_n/a_{n+1}$ converges to 1, which is all you need. That is, if $a_n/L\to 1$, then $a_n\to L$.

Answer (score 4):

Can you prove that the sequence given by:
$$ c_0=0,\quad c_1=1,\quad c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n+c_{n-1}}{2}$$
converges towards $\frac{2}{3}$? If so, just check that $d_n=\log(a_n)$ behaves the same way.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $\log a_n$ converges to $\frac{2}{3}$, but it is true that $\log a_{n+1}=\frac{\log a_n+\log a_{n-1}}{2}$. Can you see now that the sequence $\log a_n$ behaves like $c_n$? Only the initial terms are different.

Comment: @Charlie: That gives that $\log a_n$ converges towards $\frac{\log a_0+2\log a_1}{3}$. Exponentiating back, you get your claim.

Comment: Ok, it seems my technique does not work with this exercise. I cannot use the monotone convergence theorem to prove that $c_n$ converges to $\frac23$. So how should I prove that $c_n$ converges?

Comment: @Charlie: $c_n$ has a closed form: it is given by the partial sum of a geometric series. Can you prove that $$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{2^j}=\frac{2}{3}?$$

Comment: Thank you for your patience Jack. What do you mean with closed form? That you cannot extract the value of the limit from the recurrence relation?

Comment: No, I mean that you can prove $$c_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{2^j}=\frac{2}{3}\left(1-(-1/2)^n\right)$$ so it is straighforward to prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}c_n = \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @Charlie Actually your technique *does* work. See my answer on how to finish off the exercise using your original approach. Jack's answer is also good :)